# How to convert Corona lab project for Android apk build?

Tags: android, apk, coronasdk

I start to work on Corona lab framework, after done some basic I did not found way to convert it into api.

Any suggestion how to convert .lua build to .apk?

Answer (score 0):

The truth is out there:

http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/building-devices-android

adjsjd